# Soap server xml request

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a soap server with wsdl, I am new php soap and trying to make a server and a client. On soap server i am unable to get the data which client send. for example a client is sending below xml but i am unable to get the data in my register function of soap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
 <AmountRequest xmlns="http://x.x.x.x/api/">
    <OptionalClientClass />
    <OptionalClientId />
    <OptionalClientName />
   <UserId>asdas</UserId>
   <ClassId>121</ClassId>
   <SId>2082</SId>
   <AmountTypes>
    <AmountType>
      <Type>123</Type>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Price>5000</Price>
      <Optionalcode />
      <OptionalPin />
      <OptionalSequence>0</OptionalSequence>
      <OptionalProvider />
      <BookingFee>0</BookingFee>
      <ThirdParty>
        <MemberCard />
        <MemberDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</MemberDate>
      </ThirdParty>
      <Loyalty />
      <LoyaltySequence>0</LoyaltySequence>
    </AmountType>
  </AmountTypes>
  <Order>false</Order>
  <ReturnData>false</ReturnData>
  <ProcessValue>false</ProcessValue>
  <UserSupported>false</UserSupported>
  <Allocation>false</Allocation>
  <IncludePriorities>false</IncludePriorities>
  <IncludeNumbers>false</IncludeNumbers>
  <ExcludeAreas>false</ExcludeAreas>
  <ReturnInfo>false</ReturnInfo>
  <BookingFee>0</BookingFee>
  <BookingType>0</BookingType>
  <ReorderSession>false</ReorderSession>
</AmountRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

@GaneshPatil My Soap server function is

```
<?php                                                                                              
function Amount($b)
{                                                                   
$response=api_data_request($b->UserId,$b->ClassId,$b->SId,$b- >AmountTypes,$b->Order,$b->ReturnData, $b->ProcessValue, $b- >UserSupported, $b->Allocation, $b->IncludePriorities, $b- >IncludeNumbers, $b->ExcludeAreas,$b->ReturnInfo,$b-    >BookingFee,$b->BookingType,$b->ReorderSession);                   
return $response;
}
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$server = new SoapServer("http://x.x.x.x/test.wsdl",array('soap_version' =>  SOAP_1_2));                                                                         
$server->addFunction("Amount");
$server->handle();
?>
```

Comment: could you please  post your code  functions here ?

Comment: @GaneshPatil   function Amount($b)
{                                                                   
$response=api_data_request($b->UserId,$b->ClassId,$b->SId,$b- >AmountTypes,$b->Order,$b->ReturnData, $b->ProcessValue, $b- >UserSupported, $b->Allocation, $b->IncludePriorities, $b- >IncludeNumbers, $b->ExcludeAreas,$b->ReturnInfo,$b-    >BookingFee,$b->BookingType,$b->ReorderSession);                   
return $response; }